# not found nodemailer nextjs 14

Tags: next.js, axios, nodemailer

I got no found error even I write the right path "/api/sendEmail", it keep return the 404 error.
I'm using the Nextjs 14, axios and nodemailer, i thinking I'm doing everything correct.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxsuY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmfzU.png)

Comment: Please post code as text and not as picture

Comment: And no obviously you are not doing everything correct, because then it would work. But as you don't show the route definitions in your backend, it's hard to help. But when the server returns 404 on a route it's quite safe to assume it, in fact, doesn't exist

Comment: I already post the code above and i'm using a strapi as CMS and backend to create the endpoints